# If requested directory is doesn't exists in root request it from other directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

What I'm trying to do is, if the requested folder doesn't exists in the current path it should access from the other specified sub directory.

My current Folder structure is follow,

```
mysite.com/
          /index.php
          /admin/..
          /users/mike
          /users/jane
```

Now what I trying to do is, if user try to access `mysite.com/mike` request should be access from the users directory `mike` folder because `mike` doesn't exists in the root. Also if a user try access `mysite.com/users/mike` it should redirected to `mysite.com/mike`.

Comment: Are you looking for a rewrite rule or a redirect?

Comment: a rewrite rule. but if user try to access `mysite.com/users/mike` it should redirected to `mysite.com/mike`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the following line in your `mysite.com/.htaccess`:

```
Redirect mysite.com/mike mysite.com/users/mike
```

You can use [.htaccess Generator](http://www.htaccessredirect.net) to help generate htaccess options.

Comment: This only handles one of the cases for half the problem

Comment: Simply is there a way to hide users sub directory without affecting to other directories or `root` directory. Like when user try to access `mysite.com/mike` it views content from `mysite.com/users/mike` only if  doesn't exists in the `root`.